# What is the last part of this gcd proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

The statement is

$a \cdot x \equiv 1 \ (mod \ n) \iff gcd(a,n) = 1$

This "$\Leftarrow $" direction is very easy

$gcd(a,m) = 1 $

according to the Lemma of Bezout we can simply write

$ x\cdot a + y\cdot n = 1$   with  $x,y\in \mathbb Z $

After some manipulations we have something like this

$ x\cdot a = 1 - y\cdot n $

which finally is

$ x\cdot a \equiv 1 \ (mod \ n ) $

The other direction "$\Rightarrow$" is a bit more dificult. Here is my try but I am stuck.

We can write $a\cdot x \equiv 1 \ (mod \ n) $ to $a\cdot x = 1 -  k\cdot  n $ with $k\in \mathbb Z$

$a\cdot x + k\cdot n = 1$

There are integers $x,k$ which will satisfy this equation.

Now I want to use gcd

Let $d = gcd(a,n)$

But I don't know how to proceed at this point.

Comment: ... then in particular $d$ is a *divisor* of $a$ and a divisor of $n$.  Then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid n$ and therefore $d\mid (ax+kn)$...

Comment: Does that mean that d is equal to 1?

Answer (score 3):

If $x\cdot a\equiv 1$ mod $n$ then $xa+nb=1$ for some $b$. Thus $1$ is the gcd between $a$ and $n$ since each divisor of $a$ and $n$ divides 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since $d|a$ and $d|n$, hence we conclude that $d|1$.

Hence $d=1$ since the largest integer which divides $1$ is $1$.

Comment: I think I understand your point. Will this complete my proof?

Comment: I think so. Is there anything that is not convincing?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it more illuminating when expressed in *divisibility* form:

$$\begin{align} a\mid 1\!\!\!\pmod{n} \iff &\exists x\!:\, ax\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{n}\iff \exists x,y\!:\, ax+ny = 1\iff \gcd(a,n)\mid 1\\[.2em]
a\mid b\!\!\!\pmod n\iff &\exists x\!:\, ax\equiv b\!\!\pmod{n}\iff \exists x,y\!:\, ax+ny = b\iff \gcd(a,n)\mid b\end{align}$$

The final $\iff$ follows by Bezout $(\Leftarrow)$ and, conversely, $\,\gcd(a,n)\mid a,n\Rightarrow\,\gcd(a,n)\mid ax+ny$

Answer (score 0):

If $ax\equiv 1\pmod n$ then $ax=1-ny$ for some integer $y.$ If $m$ divides both $a$ and $n$ then $m$ divides both $ax$ and $ny,$ so $m$ divides their sum $ax+ny$, which is $1.$